# Restart terracotta after adding/modifying domain classes in Grails app

Tags: java, caching, grails, terracotta

We have a Grails app, and we are using Terracotta for caching. We have noticed that every time we add some fields in existing domain classes or add new domain classes, the app crashes with **"unexpected end of block of data..."** and we need to restart terracotta to get things running again.

The architecture we have is:
- Two servers behind a load balancer, running a grails app instance each
- A separate DB server
- Terracotta running on one of the web servers

Are we missing something there? Is there anything we can do to avoid having these downtimes on every domain modifying deployment?

**UPDATE:** Seems like a Terracotta issue: http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/5065.page
Version 3.5 should fix this issue. Let's just wait and hope!

Thanks,
Iraklis

Answer (score 0):

We use Terracotta for caching as well and never haven't gotten this error before. We have a similar set up as yours, two web servers behind a load balancer, but with the difference that Terracotta runs in a different set of servers, we have a cluster where one of the server is the master, not sure if this what makes the difference though but at least is an idea to try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Maricel. Indeed the key difference that I see is that Terracotta is on a separate server than the application instances themselves. We will have to re-think about our architecture and give it a try.